# Would LINQ to SQL query to SQL Server dataview be optimized as if were to a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Need to port an old Ado.net piece of code to not so old link2sql. Basically there is a SQL like below passing to database:

```
select #1 from table1 join table2
where conditions1 = true
union
select #2 from table1 join table2 
where conditions2 = true
```

I want to create a view like this:

```
select #1 from table1 join table2
union
select #2 from table1 join table2
```

and apply the conditions part in c# code to the IDataViewer object of that view.

I'm curious if applying condition this way in link2sql would be "transferred" to dataview execution plan through `IQueryable` magic.

PS: why not use functions or stored procedures? There is a sort of convention in this particular part to use dataviews. Though it is not mandatory.

Comment: What do you expect SQLServer does differently when you select from a view versus select from a table?

Comment: @CaiusJard, the selects are actually quite complex, I don't know if sqlserver would apply filters after the full select or in the process.

Comment: You'll generally find the whole query is rewritten during optimization anyway; I've always found there are amazingly few things SQLServer's optimizer can't rewrite in its mission. The only thing you can do is ask it. I'd vouch `CREATE VIEW x AS SELECT * FROM Person where name = 'smith'; SELECT * FROM x WHERE age = 20;` will be executed identically to `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = 'smith' and age = 20`

Comment: To that end, it's quite likely the answer to *Would LINQ to SQL query to MSSQL dataview be optimized as if were to a table?* would be "yes" but if you want to see if there are any minor details you'll have to execute them both and look at the plans

Comment: @CaiusJard It so happens that a `union` is one of the few places where it is difficult to do so, because it changes the semantics. Whereas `union all` is usually optimized.

Comment: @Timofeus the bigger question is of how you plan to rewrite the queries so they function identically. As presented, and syntax errors aside, you may struggle with those queries if nothing inherent in the table data can be used to identify the table the data came from so that your C# can target conditions at a particular data source. It's probably not possible to go into much further detail on a contrived foo/bar style example

Comment: @CaiusJard, there are several optional filters like id, date interval, text search.
`WHERE        
cast(Table1.TransactionDate as date) >= cast(StartDate as date) 
  AND cast(Table1.TransactionDate as date) <= cast(EndDate as date) 

AND Table2.EntityId = entityId
AND ( coalesce(FirstName, '') like 'Filter%'
AND (coalesce(Status, 0) = 1 OR SomeField > 0)`

Comment: That's fine and all doable, but you aren't doing yourself any favors manipulating table data like that. There is no need to cast dates to strip off the time when using a date range search, and do not use coalesce to provide some value for strings - leave the data alone and do `='' or is null` if you want to search for empty cells/the search term is an empty string, or do `like 'filter%'` if the search term contains something. Golden rule; do not manipulate table data in a where clause to match to search constant; it typically prevents indexes being used. Make the search constant cover the data